# Closing for off topic lacks generic reason

Tags: feature-request

The recent change to the closing mechanism has made closing for off topic (and possibly other reasons, but not the subject of this post) much more of a hassle.  When you click on "off topic", you get another screen that has only a few very specific reasons that often don't apply, then a catch-all but that forces you to write a lengthy comment.  This is a hassle.

You want us all to use the moderation tools, but you have to do your part in making them easy to use.  If you make closing for off topic difficult when we try to be honest, you are encouraging us to click whatever gets us out of there most expediently.  In other words, trying to make closing so explicit is backfiring.

Here are the close reasons currently presented:

[image]

The obvious missing choice is simply "off topic" with no further explanation required.  Note that the four canned reasons are all quite specific, so many off topic questions won't fit.  At the least there needs to be something that says "This is not directly related to electrical engineering".

When someone asks how to install PVC pipe in their basement, we really don't need to explain why that is off topic.  Making me spend time explaining why plumbing is off topic is counter-productive since I'll learn to pick some other lower-hassle reason.

Usually when I see something off topic, I first write a comment.  Then I might decide to vote to close.  That is what happened here at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/74371/4512.  The second comment is the result of being forced to enter something for the "other" reason.  To make it even more annoying, some minumum number of characters is required.  This time I got fed up and entered a bunch of dashes.  I guess I'll be doing that more and more or finding a easy close reason, whether it fits or not.

### Added in reply to W5VO

Here is what I get when clicking on "This question belongs on another site..." choice in the screen shown above:

[image]

Comment: What does the "This question belongs on another site in the StackExchange network" button bring up? (I'm pretty sure it's different for moderators). Overall it didn't seem like a bad question, and I could see how someone might have thought it would be on topic here

Comment: Since you always write a comment it sounds like you already have your reason ready.

Comment: @W5VO: I added the resulting screen to the question.

Comment: @trygvis: I don't *always* write a comment, but if I do, it will be before voting to close. I don't always remember which close reasons allow for or require a comment and which don't. Besides, I don't think of it that way. First I say something to the OP, then vote to close if appropriate. There is no reason for the extra hassle of either having to choose between a few narrow reasons or being forced to write a comment, with a significant minimum number of characters no less. If feels needlessly buearotcratic and just a little insulting.

Comment: There is a box for "other"...so what you really don't like is the fact it makes you write an explanation, when you might have already explained in a comment?

Comment: How about "other" and the explanation "don't get me started"?

Comment: @ThePhoton: Yes, it's annoying and feels tedius to have to write a comment when you already did or don't think one is needed.  It's also annoying that the nannyware enforces a certain length comment.  Let people do what they think is reasonable, else they'll find ways around it you'll like a lot less.

Comment: If you are going to close a non-malicious question, you owe the asker a truthful reason.  If you can't be bothered to provide one, then leave the closing to those who can.

Comment: @Chris: No, I don't owe some moron who just blurted out his question before reading the rules anything.  Some questions are so obviously off topic or so blatantly ignoring the rules that it's not worth dignifying them with a polite reason for closing.  We all get to *vote* on closing, so its not up to you to tell anyone else how they should vote or arrive at their opinion.  If the site tries to be a nanny to voters, we'll find a way around it.  Ultimately they can't enforce anything where we get to act on our own opinion.  Trying to do that is backlashing.

Comment: Your continued use of that word, and advocacy of gaming the site rules is evidence of how you do not belong on a public help site.

Comment: @Chris: This discussion is pointless.  You really need to stop wasting my and everyone else's time trying to tell me what I should do.  Your opinion is irrelevant to my actions.  Get over it and stop whining about it.

Comment: If you don't want to discuss the issue, stop posting your elitist rants and engaging in the associated behavior.  As it is, you really do not have an attitude compatible with a stack exchange site - it is you, not I, who has openly advocated misusing the moderation tools to account for not being given the tools you demand.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we should have this.

Some questions that are obviously off topic come from trolls. They don't deserve a correct close reason, just flag as spam and you're done. Closing troll questions is feeding the trolls.

Other questions that are obviously off topic come from plumbers and the like who for some reason think their question is on topic here. It's helpful for them to write a 30-character reason in the custom close reason and takes about 20 seconds. You can also wait for others to add that comment.

Practically, this is the same as what you're doing now, just in another order:

> Usually when I see something off topic, I first write a comment. Then I might decide to vote to close.

Comment: Having close reasons that are educationally explanatory was the motivation of the system wide revision.